# TinyMCE - the background color cannot fill the whole word

Tags: tinymce

I try to edit text by tinyMCE and do the following behavior. Then the background color cannot fill up the whole word.

1. Set font size = 18 (or greater).
2. Select strikethrough.
3. Select a text color.
4. Select a text background color.
5. Enter some text. => The background color does not fill up the text in height.

How can I fill up the whole word?

*Attach the tinyMCE editor http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyPWvb

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
    'menubar': false,
    'plugins': [
      'textcolor colorpicker '
    ],
    'toolbar1': 'strikethrough underline | ' +
        'forecolor backcolor | fontsizeselect'
});
```

Comment: Updated my answer with full example.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the problem is that tinyMCE is wrapping strikethrough and background color as separate `span` elements around selected word and the font size is applied to the inner span.

You could try [overwriting these in tinyMCE config](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/format-custom/):

```
tinymce.init({
  formats: {
    strikethrough: {inline: 'span', styles: { display: 'inline-block', 'text-decoration': 'line-through'}},
  },
  selector: 'textarea',
    'menubar': false,
    'plugins': [
      'textcolor colorpicker '
    ],
    'toolbar1': 'strikethrough underline | ' +
        'forecolor backcolor | fontsizeselect'

});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PWqBXE